# I want to replace the "content" layout in my index.html with a menu click (Spring/Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is the body of my index.html page. It specifies a static header and footer that should up on all pages. The content is what I want to change based on menu clicks.

```
<body>

<div class="container" style="width: 100% !important;">

    <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></div>

    <div th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${content}} :: ${content}"></div>

    <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Inside my header.html I have a link that looks like this, for example:

```
<li><a href="#" th:href="@{/index?content=request}">Make a Request</a></li>
```

When the user clicks this link, it should insert the fragment request.html into my content layout: `<div th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${content}} :: ${content}"></div>`. If the user clicks on a different link, such as `<li><a href="#" th:href="@{/index?content=team}">My Team</a></li>`, it should replace the content section with the fragment team.html, etc.

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
    String index(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("content", "request");
        return "index";
    }
```

Someone suggested I use the above RequestMapping model to change the content on my index page based on the above outlined menu clicks. But what do I pass in place of "request" above to get this working? As of now, I get the following for `http://localhost:8081/request`:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Feb 07 14:15:22 CET 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

How can I make the above model dynamic?

My MVC Config:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/request").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/requests").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/team").setViewName("index");
    }

}
```

No matter what, it seems to always replace the content section of my layout with `null` instead of the requested parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The goal you are trying to achive needs Thymeleaf to render the view 2 times. First, it will render `<div th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${content}} :: ${content}"></div>` as `<div th:replace="fragments/request :: request"></div>`. On second rendering, it will replace "request" content with this.

Thymeleaf doesn't work that way.

I don't also see any advantage of your approach, even if Thymeleaf supported 2 times rendering.

I suggest you to read out the tutorials Thymeleaf published on their site:

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html